# ClientToScreen unexpected return values?

Tags: c#

I never worked with windows before. I put a lot of effort into getting the correct X and Y coordinates and size of a windows, aswell as the size of the client-area of the window.

Unfortunately, X and Y of the client-area is always zero. I looked it up in the documentation and it is supposed to be zero.

On SO, I found that I need to translate the client-are coordianted to the screen coordinates by passing it to `ClientToScreen()`. However, the results are not what I expect them to be.

Instead of a Point(50,50) (or similar), I get a Point(1,57027688545264E-312, 0).

Could someone enlighten me on what's wrong?

This is my code, so far:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rect rect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref System.Windows.Point lpPoint);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rect
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    static Rectangle GetClientRect(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Rect rect;
        GetClientRect(handle, out rect);
        System.Windows.Point p = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0);
        ClientToScreen(handle, ref p);
        rect.Left = (int)p.X;
        rect.Top = (int)p.Y;
        return new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
    }
```

Comment: Is it for WPF or Forms ?

Comment: I'm writing a WPF application. Does this matter?

Comment: Not really but you're using ...LTRB from Forms so it was unclear, hang on, working on it :D

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of Point structure.  You want System.Drawing.Point, the flavor that has *int* members.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh no, such a banal mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Windows.Point` structure is not compatible with `ClientToScreen`. You should use `System.Drawing.Point` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to translate a point in window coordinates to screen coordinates and how to get the size of the window:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="ButtonClientToScreen" Content="ButtonClientToScreen" Height="20" Click="ButtonClientToScreen_Click"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="ButtonGetClientRect" Content="ButtonGetClientRect" Height="20" Click="ButtonGetClientRect_Click"  ></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private IntPtr GetHandle()
        {
            var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            var handle = helper.Handle;
            return handle;
        }

        private void ButtonClientToScreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // convert a point in window coords to screen coords
            var handle = GetHandle();
            var point = new NativePoint {x = 50, y = 50};
            var clientToScreen = NativeMethods.ClientToScreen(handle, ref point);
            if (clientToScreen)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, string.Format("ClientToScreen: {0}", point));
            }
        }

        private void ButtonGetClientRect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // get window size
            var handle = GetHandle();
            NativeRect rect;
            var clientRect = NativeMethods.GetClientRect(handle, out rect);
            if (clientRect)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, string.Format("GetClientRect: {0}", rect));
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct NativeRect
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Left: {left}, Top: {top}, Right: {right}, Bottom: {bottom}";
        }
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct NativePoint
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"X: {x}, Y: {y}";
        }
    }

    public class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClientRect")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetClientRect([In] IntPtr hWnd, [Out] out NativeRect lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ClientToScreen")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool ClientToScreen([In] IntPtr hWnd, ref NativePoint lpPoint);
    }
}
```

To transform the window rect to screen coordinates :

- call GetClientRect
- call ClientToScreen with x=0, y=0
- offset received rect by GetClientRect by the amount received by ClientToScreen

**EDIT 1:**

try move/resize the window and press the buttons, you'll understand how all this works.

**EDIT 2:**

Here's how to convert your window coords/size to screen:

```
    private void ButtonWindowToScreenRect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handle = GetHandle();
        var point = new NativePoint();
        NativeMethods.ClientToScreen(handle, ref point);
        NativeRect rect;
        NativeMethods.GetClientRect(handle, out rect);

        var win2screenRect = new NativeRect
        {
            left = rect.left + point.x,
            right = rect.right + point.x,
            top = rect.top + point.y,
            bottom = rect.bottom + point.y
        };
        MessageBox.Show(this, win2screenRect.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Aybe, thanks for your effort and I am sure this will come in handy for other people :) However, the answer is a little bit too much, to be marked as such. Ivan nailed it.