Translating rectangle coordinates to screen coordinates for screen capture
I am working on creating a screen capture app in C# using WPF, where the user can draw a rectangle on the screen, and the app captures the content behind that rectangle, similar to the Windows Snipping Tool.
I'm stuck on how to convert the coordinates of the drawn rectangle to screen coordinates. Below is the code I have so far.
The screen capture only captures part of the drawn rectangle
<Window x:Class="ScreenCapture.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Screen Capture" Height="800" Width="1660"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"
        PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.01" Color="White"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Transparent"
            MouseDown="canvas_MouseDown" 
            MouseUp="canvas_MouseUp">
    </Canvas>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Drawing; // For screen capturing (Bitmap, Graphics)
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ScreenCapture
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle DragRectangle = null; // Specify WPF Rectangle
        private System.Windows.Point StartPoint, LastPoint;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape) { this.Close(); e.Handled = true; }
        }

        private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            StartPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
            LastPoint = StartPoint;

            // Initialize and style the rectangle
            DragRectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
            {
                Width = 1,
                Height = 1,
                Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Cursor = Cursors.Cross
            };

            // Add the rectangle to the canvas
            canvas.Children.Add(DragRectangle);
            Canvas.SetLeft(DragRectangle, StartPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(DragRectangle, StartPoint.Y);

            // Attach the mouse move and mouse up events
            canvas.MouseMove += canvas_MouseMove;
            canvas.MouseUp += canvas_MouseUp;
            canvas.CaptureMouse();
        }

        private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DragRectangle == null) return;

            // Update LastPoint to current mouse position
            LastPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);

            // Update rectangle dimensions and position
            DragRectangle.Width = Math.Abs(LastPoint.X - StartPoint.X);
            DragRectangle.Height = Math.Abs(LastPoint.Y - StartPoint.Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(DragRectangle, Math.Min(LastPoint.X, StartPoint.X));
            Canvas.SetTop(DragRectangle, Math.Min(LastPoint.Y, StartPoint.Y));
        }

        private void canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DragRectangle == null) return;

            // Release mouse capture and remove event handlers
            canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            //canvas.MouseMove -= canvas_MouseMove;
            //canvas.MouseUp -= canvas_MouseUp;

            // Get coordinates for the capture area
            int x = (int)Math.Min(LastPoint.X, StartPoint.X);
            int y = (int)Math.Min(LastPoint.Y, StartPoint.Y);
            int width = (int)Math.Abs(LastPoint.X - StartPoint.X);
            int height = (int)Math.Abs(LastPoint.Y - StartPoint.Y);

            // Ensure dimensions are valid before capture
            if (width > 0 && height > 0)
            {
                CaptureScreen(x, y, width, height);
            }

            //// Clean up: remove rectangle from canvas
            //canvas.Children.Remove(DragRectangle);
            //DragRectangle = null;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void CaptureScreen(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            // Convert WPF coordinates to screen coordinates
            var screenLeft = (int)(PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(x, y)).X);
            var screenTop = (int)(PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(x, y)).Y);

            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    // Capture the area of the screen based on converted coordinates
                    g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));
                }

                // Save the captured image to the desktop
                string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, $"Screenshot_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.png");
                bitmap.Save(filePath);
                MessageBox.Show($"Screenshot saved to {filePath}");
            }
        }

    }
}


Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534279/clienttoscreen-unexpected-return-values of any help? That answer is pretty old (2015), and calls a Windows API function. It's possible that WPF has a client-to-screen function these days.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/4226740/1136211

I'd capture a "visual" of the Rectangle, with a Transparent Fill, and defined Border; and see if it also captured what's behind; in order to see if that meets your requirements (more easily). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-encode-a-visual-to-an-image-file?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Thanks to everyone for your help! Special thanks to Jim Mischel for pointing me in the right direction.
In WPF, there's a handy method called PointToScreen that helped me solve the issue. This method converts a point relative to a WPF element to screen coordinates, which was exactly what I needed.
using System;
using System.Drawing; // For screen capturing (Bitmap, Graphics)
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ScreenCapture
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle DragRectangle = null; // Specify WPF Rectangle
        private System.Windows.Point StartPoint, LastPoint;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }

        private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape) { this.Close(); e.Handled = true; }
        }

        private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            StartPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
            LastPoint = StartPoint;

            // Initialize and style the rectangle
            DragRectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
            {
                Width = 1,
                Height = 1,
                Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Cursor = Cursors.Cross
            };

            // Add the rectangle to the canvas
            canvas.Children.Add(DragRectangle);
            Canvas.SetLeft(DragRectangle, StartPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(DragRectangle, StartPoint.Y);

            // Attach the mouse move and mouse up events
            canvas.MouseMove += canvas_MouseMove;
            canvas.MouseUp += canvas_MouseUp;
            canvas.CaptureMouse();
        }

        private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DragRectangle == null) return;

            // Update LastPoint to current mouse position
            LastPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);

            // Update rectangle dimensions and position
            DragRectangle.Width = Math.Abs(LastPoint.X - StartPoint.X);
            DragRectangle.Height = Math.Abs(LastPoint.Y - StartPoint.Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(DragRectangle, Math.Min(LastPoint.X, StartPoint.X));
            Canvas.SetTop(DragRectangle, Math.Min(LastPoint.Y, StartPoint.Y));
        }

        private void canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DragRectangle == null) return;
            canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();

            CaptureScreen();

            // Clean up: remove rectangle from canvas
            canvas.Children.Remove(DragRectangle);
            DragRectangle = null;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void CaptureScreen()
        {
            // Convert StartPoint and LastPoint to screen coordinates
            var screenStart = PointToScreen(StartPoint);
            var screenEnd = PointToScreen(LastPoint);

            // Calculate the capture area dimensions and position
            int x = (int)Math.Min(screenStart.X, screenEnd.X);
            int y = (int)Math.Min(screenStart.Y, screenEnd.Y);
            int width = (int)Math.Abs(screenEnd.X - screenStart.X);
            int height = (int)Math.Abs(screenEnd.Y - screenStart.Y);


            this.Closed += (s, e) => 
            {
                // Ensure dimensions are valid before capture
                if (width > 0 && height > 0)
                {
                    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
                    {
                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                        {
                            // Capture the area of the screen based on converted coordinates
                            g.CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, new System.Drawing.Size(width, height));
                        }

                        // Save the captured image to the desktop
                        string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, $"Screenshot_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.png");
                        bitmap.Save(filePath);

                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                        { FileName = filePath, UseShellExecute = true });
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}


